# Middleware redirect in Asp.net core Blazor server-side 3.0 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, f#, asp.net-core-3.0

I am currently testing out an asp.net core 3 blazor server-side app. I built a middleware extension in f#, and called it from c# within the Configure method of the Startup class.  It appears to initially attempt the redirect as the correct url is called, but I get an error page stating that the page isn't redirecting properly. What am I missing here.

F#:

```
type CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWare(next : RequestDelegate) =

    let _next = next

    member this.InvokeAsync(context : HttpContext) =

        let statusCheck = true
        if statusCheck
        then 
            Task.Run(fun arg -> context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance"))
        else 
           _next.Invoke(context)

[<Extension>]
type CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWareExtensions() =

    [<Extension>]
    static member inline UseCheckMaintenanceStatus(builder : IApplicationBuilder) =

        builder.UseMiddleware<CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWare>()
```

C#

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCheckMaintenanceStatus();

            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }



            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

Razor Component:

```
@page "/Maintenance"

<h3>Maintenance</h3>

@code {

}
```

Comment: Seems that your code makes the browser redirect all the time?

Comment: If that's the case, please check whether current path is `/Maintenance` to avoid redirect-loop: `if statusCheck && context.Request.Path.Value <> "/Maintenance"  then`

Comment: Note that you don’t need `let _next = next`, you can use `next` directly. Also, creating Tasks by scheduling on the threadpool is costly (for various reasons), consider using `Task.FromResult`

Comment: @itminus Your suggestion worked. Can you submit this as an answer so that I may accept it.  Also can your provide an explanation within in your answer as to how the loop is created in this situation.

Comment: @CaringDev Can you explain a bit in more detail how to do this. I haven't seen any examples of this in the documentation for middleware construction, and in regards to my if statement I was just trying be consistent with next.Invoke in which returns type Task.

Comment: @user1206480 this is more suited for CodeReview. Please post a question there (and ping me in a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirect-loop might happens as below:

```
                                              (redirect-loop might happens)
Request Process Starts                       <---------------------------+
 |----->  CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWare                               |
              (check status)                                             |
                  if fail then redirect to '/Maintenance' -------------->|
                  else 
                       |----> go to inner middlewares by next(context)
```

To avoid the endless redirect loop, check whether the current path has already been changed to `/Maintenance`:

```ml
if statusCheck && context.Request.Path.Value <> "/Maintenance" then
    ... redirect
else
    ... invoke inner middlewares
```